# ¿Cómo llenar los campos para conexión a base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, web

estoy creando una web con conexión a base de datos. El servicio de hosting me lo otorga godaddy pero no sé cómo llenar las variables para crear la conexión desde php a mysql.

```
<?php
 $host = "";
 $user = "";
 $pass = "";
 $name = "";

 $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);
 mysqli_select_db($con, $name);
?>
```

Es decir ¿Qué debería poner en $host, $user, $pass, $name? Soy principiante así que una explicación bien detallada no estaría mal :)

Comment: Información detallada: [aquí](https://es.godaddy.com/help/como-ver-los-detalles-de-la-base-de-datos-con-cuentas-de-hosting-compartidas-39) y [aquí](https://es.godaddy.com/help/conexion-a-mysql-usando-php-216)...

Answer (score 1):

Imaginemos que tu servidor BD corre en *mysql.godaddy.com* (goddady te otorga estos datos en un correo con tus datos de acceso), tu tienes el nombre de usuario *aabarca*, contraseña de BD *lx5YZ7K* y quieres usar la base de datos *wordpress0137*.

En este caso el codigo sería:

```
$host = "mysql.godaddy.com";
$user = "aabarca";
$pass = "lx5YZ7K";
$name = "wordpress0137";
```

- host - la dirección del servidor de BD en que tienes tu base de datos
- user - el nombre de usuario para la BD (no necesariamente lo mismo que tu cuenta, tu proveedor te lo otorga.
- pass - la contraseña otorgado por tu proveedor para el usuario
- name - el nombre de la BD que tu puedes usar en este servidor

Ten en cuenta que dependiente de tu plan de hosting te permiten acceso a una cantidad limitada de bases de datos, o la opción de crear bases de datos según tus necesidades.